# Passing an object between different classes?

Tags: php, oop, data-structures, message-passing

I've always passed data manually between different classes. So for example I had some data produced by one class:

```
$someData = $Object->someMethod();
$moreData = $Object2->anotherMethod($someData);
```

But it feels clunky to me and it results in messy code that gets complicated. Especially if there are multiple different kinds of data passed around multiple classes.

So instead of doing that I've decided I will create a class DataContainer that groups every variable related to the process and then I will just pass this object around different classes. As it passes the processing pipeline, it will gather more and more data until almost every of its field is set to some value.

So for example I have a pipeline of processing data that gets modified by 4 different classes - instead of passing the data by value I will pass it by reference:

```
$myObject = $class1->method1(); // this class returns the DataContainer object
$class2->method2($myObject);
$class3->method3($myObject);
$class4->method4($myObject);
```

Is it considered a better choice? Or is there something better?

Comment: Looks fine... passing a data container around is very common, and is good practice. However, if you want to know how you could improve your code, I'd recommend posting the actual code [on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know this existed.

Comment: this article about registry pattern might interest you http://avedo.net/101/the-registry-pattern-and-php/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind to make your code SOLID. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))
In your case, you can create in the constructor of class2 a reference.

For example:

```
<?php
class Class1
{
  private $class2;
  public __construct(Class2 $class2)
  {
     $this->class2 = $class2;
  }

  public function CallMethodOfClass2()
  {
     $value = $this->class2->GetMethod();
     $propertyValue = $this->class2->public_property;
  }
}
?>
```

Or when your Class2 cant exists without Class1, make in the constructor of Class1 a new instance of Class2 like this:

```
<?php
    class Class1
    {
      private $class2;
      public __construct()
      {
         $this->class2 = new Class2();
      }

      public function CallMethodOfClass2()
      {
         $value = $this->class2->GetMethod();
         $propertyValue = $this->class2->public_property;
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: For all you know, the OP's code might be fully solid compliant, which yours isn't (`Class 1` doesn't allow injection of `Class2`). Also [adhere to the standards](http://www.php-fig.org) as much as possible (`CallMethodOfClass2` should begin with a lower case), and don't use the closing `?>` tag, if your file only contains PHP code]

Comment: Code can be SOLID even its get something injected. Your class can be depended of something, thats no problem. For example, a database connection class, can be implemented in multiple classes but stay SOLID. The class keeps is own responsibilty. I program .NET so there we use Uppercase, its just a coding style ;-) For closingtag, in the past someone told me to use always the closingtag in stackoverflow...

Comment: The `D` in SOLID stands for Dependency Injection, so yes, dependencies and injection don't contradict SOLID (quite the opposite). Your second snippet has an undeclared, non-injectable dependency, which isn't recommended. According to the official PHP docs [the closing tag is to be avoided](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem wouldn't there be problems when including multiple not-tag-closed php files?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: No, what makes you think that?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Now that you ask me, it does seem less logical, but I would have thought that multiple opening php tags in row could break something in the php parser, but then, they are not exactly within the same script if `include()`ed